# Cant start UNO UWP project

Tags: uwp, uno-platform

I've created a new UNO project from template ,
when i try to start the UWP head, it want start , it compile successfully but never start
I've noted that the UWP head is missing the App.xaml witch is normally exists in UWP projects

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it seams that my PC was unhappy , i did a restart it and it  worked

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `App.xaml` file is located in the `App1.Shared` project, rather than the UWP head, so it can be shared by all platforms. You can read more about [Uno's default project structure here](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-app-solution-structure.html).